# Where do I direct the action for an HTML form in a Gmail add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to create an HTML form to be used for sign-in. I specifically need to be able to use the `<input type="password" />` functionality.

```html
<form>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Email: </td>
    <td><input name="email" type="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password: </td>
    <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="log in" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My issue is that I'm not sure what the `action` should be or if that is even how I am supposed to capture the information in the form.

How do I capture the form data so that I can send it to my API and verify the log in?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: You can give them each a unique ID and when they push the login button use jquery val() to grab the data and send it via parameters to an apps script function via google.script.run

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments... you cannot use HTML markup. You must use [widgets in a Card](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/). I'm not aware of a widget that hides its input.

Also, the person using your add-on has already logged into Gmail and you can get their email address. So you could simply send their email address to your API, knowing that they have authenticated already. (Make sure your API only trusts the Gmail server for this.)